# cycle through one command's output and use in another command

Tags: shell, text-processing, pipe, xargs

How can I use the output of one command - line-by-line - into another command? I know how to do this with the `|` pipe symbol, but this uses the entire output in one command. I would like to go line by line... I think I need to combine the `|` and `xargs` but not sure.

```
redis-cli keys \* | redis-cli get [key would go here]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use while to loop through each line:

```
redis-cli-keys \* | while read key; do redis-cli get "$key"; done
```

Comment: awesome thank you! is the term `read` always going to be in those types of commands?

Comment: `read` can be used in a lot of instances.  For example, as a standalone to take input and assign to a variable (with a prompt): `read -p "Enter a name: " name` - the value entered will then be assigned to `$name`.

Comment: Very cool, i'll look into that. thanks again - this worked!

Comment: `read` is also handy to assign words in a string to variables: `x="1 2 3 4 5"; read a b c rest <<< "$x"`

Answer (score 9):

The [xargs](http://man.cx/xargs) answer would be:

```
redis-cli keys \* | xargs -L 1 redis-cli get
```

Answer (score 4):

Just for completeness here's the `for` loop variant:

```
$ for key in $(redis-cli-keys \*); do redis-cli get $key; done
```

**NOTE:** This works so long as the `$keys` do not contain spaces.